# How to zoom-in without having the image blurred in Irfanview

Tags: zoom, irfanview

How can I zoom-in without having the image blurred in Irfanview? I need it for GUI development to see large pixels.

Comment: What type of files are they, and does if Infranview can't do it, does it have to be that program?

Comment: Usually, it are screenshots. Well, IrfanView is my choice of small and fast image viewer since ages. I've tried a couple of alternatives, but they lack at different areas - mostly in usability.

Comment: The exact file type matters. Some scale (.jpg), some are pixels (.gif)

Comment: I'm talking about **screenshots** (taken with [Alt+]Print, then pasted), not about viewing files.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I found the solution by reading [changelog](http://www.irfanview.com/history_old.htm)

> New display option: Use Resample for zooming (Menu: View->Display options)

So from "View" menu, select "Display options" and turn off "Use resample".

Comment: I had to adjust zoom for the setting to kick in.

Comment: Thanks--I've been wondering why suddenly Irfanview was no longer giving me a precise zoomed view of my images!

Comment: Thanks!  baffling to me that there are a separate set of options which are not under the Options menu.

Comment: There is now an option specifically for zoom under View -> Display options -> Use Resample for zooming

Comment: There is also a separate option for when you're in full screen mode at "Options > Properties/Settings > Full screen > Use Resample function for zooming".

Answer (score -7):

What you're looking for is technically known as "Nearest Neighbor Interpolation".

i would use an application like

- Microsoft's ZoomIt
- Magnifier
- Photoshop

they all 'preserve hard edges of pixels'.